# late evening/the late evening/a late evening

Tags: articles

> 1 It's a/the/- late evening **now**.
>
> 2 It was a/the/- late evening when he arrived.
>
> 3 It was a/the/- evening when he arrived.
>
> 4 I always have a nap in a/the/- late afternoon

I am confused as to which article is correct and why. Any guidelines?

Comment: Definite article ***the*** would be acceptable (albeit a bit "literary") for the first three contexts, but normally they would all feature the "zero article" (no determiner at all). The fourth example would ***always*** feature the definite article.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Morning'-->countable or uncountable?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/204159/morning-countable-or-uncountable)

Comment: I maybe dumb, but I don't know how it can solve the issue

Comment: _It was an evening in March/a late evening in March_ can be used if the date has not been previously specified, but if we know what day is being referred to it's _it was evening_.

Comment: Related / possible duplicates: [What is the difference between "all day" and "all the day"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/201397/what-is-the-difference-between-all-day-and-all-the-day) AND ["all of the day" or "all day"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/263726/all-of-the-day-or-all-day) AND ['all' , 'all the', 'all of the', and 'the whole'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36721/all-all-the-all-of-the-and-the-whole)

Comment: FF, how does "all" fall into this category?

Comment: Why can't 4 have ZERO? 4 I always have a nap in late afternoon